# How to upload a folder of images using php and mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, xampp

Basically I have to create a jukebox type chart via mysql and php using xampp. 
I've done the basics of setting up the table my referring to mysql database etc. I just don't get how to code the path to the image folder I have created. My Image folder is in htdocs under my folder I created called Jukebox. This is my coding:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
table, th, td {
     border: 1px solid black;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "jukebox";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
     die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "SELECT * FROM Music";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
     echo "<table>

     <tr>

     <th>Artist</th>
     <th>Title</th>
     <th>Album</th>
     <th>Albumcover</th>
     <th>Play</th>
     </tr>";


// output data of each row
     while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

         echo 

         "<tr>

         <td>" . $row["Artist"]. "</td>
         <td>" . $row["Title"]. "</td>
         <td>" . $row["Album"]. "</td>
         <td>" . $row["Albumcover"] 
         . "</td>
         <td>" . $row["Play"] . "</td>

         </tr>";
     }
     echo "</table>";

} else {
     echo "0 results";
} ?>         
</body>
</html>
```

[This is what my php coding looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9byvq.png)

[This is my image folder which i wish to create a path to so that all the album art can come up in the albumcover column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jgivi.png)

How do I create this path with php and mysql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<style>
.preview
{
    width:400px;
    border:solid 1px #dedede;
    padding:10px;
    color:#cc0000;

}
</style>
<?php
 // output data of each row
 while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

     echo 

     "<tr>

     <td>" . $row["Artist"]. "</td>
     <td>" . $row["Title"]. "</td>
     <td>" . $row["Album"]. "</td>
     <td><img class='preview' src='jukebox/img/" . $row["Albumcover"] ."' alt=".$row["Albumcover"]."></td>
     <td>" . $row["Play"] . "</td>

     </tr>";
 }
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked but within the albumcover column each reffered image has come up as a small icon of a torn image

Comment: Thats something you should do in css

Comment: use css to make borders that is simple

Comment: Could you help me with another issue in regards to uploading mp3's in my play collumn on the table, like how would i go about putting that into coding? I'm assuming it's similar to the albumart coding

Comment: so could you help?

Comment: what you exactly need? you need mp3 in your table?

Comment: Okay, yeah basically, I've created another question called "How do I create a directory path on PHP" if you look for that, it should be clearer

Answer (score 0):

No need to do anything special. You are working from a `base directory` of `/jukebox/`, your images reside in `/jukebox/img/`. Let's make it work:

```
<img src=\"/jukebox/img/".$row['Albumcover']."\"/>
```

Within your loop. Now the album cover will appear as an image in that row.

Comment: Where in my coding would I put this?

Comment: Could you be more specific location in my current coding? Because it's not working where I'm putting it, sorry.

Comment: @NahedahAhmed You would want to have it within your loop, so you can properly reference the row, such as this: `<td>" . $row["Albumcover"] ."</td>`

Comment: I've already tried this and it didnt work for me ...i put it together like this 

 <td>" . $row["Albumcover"] ."    
  echo    '<img src="/jukebox/img/'.$row['Albumcover'].'"/>'; </td>

Comment: @NahedahAhmed You can't embed an `echo` from within a `concatenated string`. I didn't realize that you didn't know these things, sorry. I've edited my answer and provided the exact code that you should put between your `<td></td>` tag.